# react-native-step-indicator not working with react-native v0.52.0

Tags: react-native

I'll try to use [react-native-step-indicator](https://github.com/24ark/react-native-step-indicator) with the react-native project. But it returned this error.
**undefined is not an object (evaluating 'React.PropTypes.func')**

Here is my package.json file.

```js
{
  "name": "app-test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "firebase": "^4.9.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.52.0",
    "react-native-android-kit": "^1.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.0.0-alpha.40",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.11.1",
    "react-native-paged-scroll-view": "^2.0.4",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.33",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^4.0.0-beta.28",
    "react-native-step-indicator": "0.0.7",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^0.0.74",
    "react-native-tabs": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-viewpager": "^0.2.13",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.27",
    "victory": "^0.25.4",
    "victory-native": "^0.17.0"
  }
}
```

And this is the page that I want to integrate step-indicator.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,StyleSheet,View, Text } from 'react-native';
import ViewPager from 'react-native-viewpager';
import StepIndicator from 'react-native-step-indicator';
const PAGES = ['Page 1','Page 2','Page 3','Page 4','Page 5'];

const firstIndicatorStyles = {
  stepIndicatorSize: 30,
  currentStepIndicatorSize:40,
  separatorStrokeWidth: 3,
  currentStepStrokeWidth: 5,
  separatorFinishedColor: '#4aae4f',
  separatorUnFinishedColor: '#a4d4a5',
  stepIndicatorFinishedColor: '#4aae4f',
  stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: '#a4d4a5',
  stepIndicatorCurrentColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
  currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 15,
  stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#000000',
  stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.5)',
  labelColor: '#666666',
  labelSize: 12,
  currentStepLabelColor: '#4aae4f'
}

const secondIndicatorStyles = {
  stepIndicatorSize: 25,
  currentStepIndicatorSize:30,
  separatorStrokeWidth: 2,
  currentStepStrokeWidth: 3,
  stepStrokeCurrentColor: '#fe7013',
  stepStrokeWidth: 3,
  stepStrokeFinishedColor: '#fe7013',
  stepStrokeUnFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
  separatorFinishedColor: '#fe7013',
  separatorUnFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
  stepIndicatorFinishedColor: '#fe7013',
  stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorCurrentColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 13,
  currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 13,
  stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: '#fe7013',
  stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: '#aaaaaa',
  labelColor: '#999999',
  labelSize: 13,
  currentStepLabelColor: '#fe7013'
}

const thirdIndicatorStyles = {
  stepIndicatorSize: 25,
  currentStepIndicatorSize:30,
  separatorStrokeWidth: 2,
  currentStepStrokeWidth: 3,
  stepStrokeCurrentColor: '#7eaec4',
  stepStrokeWidth: 3,
  stepStrokeFinishedColor: '#7eaec4',
  stepStrokeUnFinishedColor: '#dedede',
  separatorFinishedColor: '#7eaec4',
  separatorUnFinishedColor: '#dedede',
  stepIndicatorFinishedColor: '#7eaec4',
  stepIndicatorUnFinishedColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorCurrentColor: '#ffffff',
  stepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
  currentStepIndicatorLabelFontSize: 0,
  stepIndicatorLabelCurrentColor: 'transparent',
  stepIndicatorLabelFinishedColor: 'transparent',
  stepIndicatorLabelUnFinishedColor: 'transparent',
  labelColor: '#999999',
  labelSize: 13,
  currentStepLabelColor: '#7eaec4'
}

export default class E2 extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    var dataSource = new ViewPager.DataSource({
      pageHasChanged: (p1, p2) => p1 !== p2,
    });
    this.state = {
      dataSource: dataSource.cloneWithPages(PAGES),
      currentPage:0
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.stepIndicator}>
          <StepIndicator customStyles={firstIndicatorStyles} currentPosition={this.state.currentPage} labels={["Account","Profile","Band","Membership","Dashboard"]} />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  renderViewPagerPage = (data) => {
    return(<View style={styles.page}>
      <Text>{data}</Text>
    </View>)
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
  },
  stepIndicator: {
    marginVertical:50,
  },
  page: {
    flex:1,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  }
});
```

How can I solve this error, I appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Is there a specific line of code that error points to? I do not get an error when I try the package with your code in a new project.

Comment: I feel the error comes with **ViewPager** part.
```
var dataSource = new ViewPager.DataSource({
      pageHasChanged: (p1, p2) => p1 !== p2,
    });
```

Comment: @MichaelCheng Can you share your test code with me?

Comment: please help me for this    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424607/how-to-implement-custom-label-in-stepindicator-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

It's working with

`"react-native": "0.54.2"`

in pure Native environment. 
Try it with with latest dependencies i gues.

Comment: it is rather than a comment instead of posting the answer to the question

Comment: You can get the reputation easily, try these [steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) and help the community...

Comment: Thanks very much @Bruce

Comment: could you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424607/how-to-implement-custom-label-in-stepindicator-in-react-native'

Answer (score 0):

React.Proptypes is deprecated in React v15.5.0,
this library is migrated from React.PropTypes to `prop-types` in the latest version.

So:

1. install latest version
2. `import PropTypes from 'prop-types';`
3. enjoy!

Comment: could you please help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56424607/how-to-implement-custom-label-in-stepindicator-in-react-native'